# How to find if required weekday is between given two dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns in_date and out_date in my dataframe. I need to check if I have weekend(Saturday, Sunday) in between the given two dates?

```py
Input

df['in_date']   df['out_date']
04/04/19        08/04/19
01/05/19        03/05/19
01/05/19        06/05/19    

Expected Output
df['in_date']   df['out_date']     df['Weekend]
04/04/19        08/04/19                Y
01/05/19        03/05/19                N
01/05/19        06/05/19                Y
```

I am able to get weekday with the following code:

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['checkin_date'],format='%d/%m/%y').dt.dayofweek
```

But unable to find the logic to check if weekend is between the given dates.
Can anybody help me to achieve the above logic. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want both (Sat, Sun) in the range to be `True` or just one of them?

Comment: @ResidentSleeper Both

Comment: There's something I'm missing if both are required. Accepted answer returns `True` for `01/05/19, 04/05/19` range

Comment: @LanteDellarovere. That is expected.

Comment: ok, but I can't get why. There is no Sunday in that range. I'm feeling dumb.

Comment: I m trying to figure out if the person has entered in or moved out on a weekend.

Comment: what person? also, `05/05/19,06/05/19` returns `True` and are a Sunday and a Monday. Is that expected as well?

Comment: Yes. My df has checkin date and checkout date. if indate is 05/05/19,out date is 06/05/19, then the person has checkedin on Sunday and True is expected.

Comment: ok perfect, I see. answer to @ResidentSleeper question is "just one of them" then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. Hopefully somebody will post something shorter and better:

```
((pd.to_datetime(df['out_date'],format='%d/%m/%y') - pd.to_datetime(df['in_date'],format='%d/%m/%y')).dt.days + pd.to_datetime(df['in_date'],format='%d/%m/%y').dt.dayofweek)  > 4
```